# Redirect to a URL with trailing slash fails - application context is ignored

Tags: java, url, websphere, relative-path, contextpath

I have defined a welcome page in my web.xml and I'm deploying on WebSphere.

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>main.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

I have my js files located as below

```
WebContent > static > js > myJsFile.js
```

My JSP is located directly under WebContent. In my JSP I'm trying to load the JS file

```
<head>
<script id="loader" type="text/javascript" src="static/js/myJsFile.js"></script>
</head>
```

The problem is It fails to load the file. I'm getting 404. When I checked the Chrome DevTools I can see that the url for fetching the file fails to consider the application context. The url it is trying to use is as below **which lacks the app context**.

```
http://localhost:9080/static/js/myJsFile.js
```

I know I can get the context by using <%=request.getContextPath();%> but according to the **servlet spec** the container should do a redirect from /myapp to a URI with a trailing slash /myapp/ automatically.

In my JavaScript file I'm loading so many other JS files which in this case will fail as well.

Could someone explain why?

**UPDATE:** I investigated a bit on a separate application which is working fine and managed to find that as soon as the browser hit http://localhost:9080/myapp there is a 302 redirect to http://localhost:9080/myapp/ **(notice the trailing slash)**.
In my application the container never redirect. If there is a redirect then everything works fine.

**UPDATE:**
I found a link about a known bug on WAS 8.5 ([404 NOT FOUND ERROR GENERATED FOR A REQUEST WITHOUT A TRAILING SLASH](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI22830)). According to them I have the fix pack but still my issue is not resolved.

Another thing is in my pom.xml I've changed the **contextRoot**  (/myapp) of my application.

Comment: did you try `<script id="loader" type="text/javascript" src="./static/js/myJsFile.js"></script>`?

Comment: yes, and its not working